# Eclipse does not seem to compile servlet, causing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: eclipse, servlets, classnotfoundexception

Currently I am using Ubuntu 12.04LTS , Eclipse IDE and Apache Tomcat 7.0.27 and I am not getting the job done.

I made a simple jsp page "index.jsp" which is in "WebContent/index.jsp". I made a servlet called "EmployeeClass" which is inside the package "com.pack.web".
In Jsp page I have a form with get method and a action as follow:

```
<form method="GET" action="hidden.do">
```

In web.xml I also have:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Searcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.pack.web.EmployeeClass</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Searcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hidden.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I made a simple servlet "EmployeeClass", it's in package:

```
package com.pack.web;
```

in this servlet I have a doGet method as:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Something is happening");
}
```

I finally then run my project and after hitting the submit button, bang I have this:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class com.pack.web.EmployeeClass
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

root cause

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pack.web.EmployeeClass
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: are your classes in the the ClassPath? the default folder is WEB-INF/classes, can you double check it?

Comment: Check your project setting for the compilation paths.

Comment: @PbxMan No there are no any classes in the WEB-INF/classes. My servlet is not compiling.

Answer (score 3):

Finally at last after 2 weeks 15hrs and 34min I found the solution. The problem was solved by turning on automatic build which was apparently accidentally turned off.

> Project -> Build Automatically